# php bin/console as:in:web - there is no commands defined in the "as:in" namespace

Tags: php, symfony

I'm getting this error on **php bin/console as:in:web**:

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
>     There are no commands defined in the "as:in" namespace.
>     Did you mean one of these?
>         doctrine:mapping
>         generate:doctrine
>         assets
>         assetic

**php bin/console server:run** command works normally.

On other machines, the command works in this project properly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where did you stumble upon the reference of this command? Google does not show much of it...

Comment: But, I would guess that the command belongs to some third-party bundle and that it was not installed/activated...

Comment: If it only works on some machines, you might not be loading whatever bundle contains that command in the default environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking you are wanting this command instead:

```
php bin/console assets:install
```

That's the only one that makes sense and is 'close'. Is that what you were looking to do - I mean install web assets